# Kali Linux: Device won't switch Wi-Fi region

Tags: linux, wireless-networking

I have been using Linux for a while now, but I recently installed Linux on my old Windows laptop.

I live in Germany, which uses the WiFi channels 1-13.
However, `iw phy` only shows channels 1-11 to be enabled, whereas `iw reg get` returns this.

```
global
country DE: DFS-ETSI
    (2400 - 2483 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (5150 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 23), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW
    (5250 - 5350 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), NO-OUTDOOR, DFS, AUTO-BW
    (5470 - 5725 @ 160), (N/A, 26), (0 ms), DFS
    (5725 - 5875 @ 80), (N/A, 13), (N/A)
    (5945 - 6425 @ 160), (N/A, 23), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR
    (57000 - 66000 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)

phy#0
country 99: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (5140 - 5360 @ 80), (N/A, 30), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5460 - 5860 @ 80), (N/A, 30), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
```

`/etc/default/crda` is set to `DE`, and `iw reg set` has no effect.

Is there any way I can change the region of the `phy#0` device?

Comment: bumping this...